# Connecting to postgresql with password only

Tags: postgresql, debian

I installed Postgresql 9.5 using the Debian Postgresql repository from postgresql.org, and later enabled remote connections. I then later added a password to the postgres user by using the following

```
su - postgres
psql
\password postgres
```

I did set a password successfully, but I can still connect to postgresql using pgadmin3 without providing a password.

What did I miss in the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In my pg_hba.conf at the end I had

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

I changed it to

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

and now it asks for password